# Custom line caps?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

As in [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/CapsStyle.html) adobe documentation, there is only three types of caps for drawing lines:

square, round, none.

Isn't there a custom shape for caps style? anyone knows? : )

Comment: The documentation says there are only 3, but if you need to accomplish some shape in particular, maybe someone can help you with the code if you shared your idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's only 3 types of CapsStyle available in actionscript-3. 
However if you want another types of CapsStyle you have to extend a class where you want to implement. 
For example if  you want to implement on graphics.lineTo() function then you have to extend graphics class to your own yourgraphics class and override the lineTo method and add another capsstyle type.

Pretty much complex I guess.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because the new class is out of context, unless I can say myShape.graphics= myNewGraphics; well?